# Is there any solution available which supports 2FA in OpenLDAP for user authentication?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, openldap

Currently we are using **SimpleSAMLphp** for SSO solution in our php application with OpenLDAP as a auth datasource and it's working fine.

Now we need to implement 2FA in the login process, So I wanted to know if there is any inbuilt support for 2FA in OpenLDAP.

I have found **SimpleSAMLphp** allows 2FA using **PrivacyIDEA** module, But it uses it's own mechanism for totp generation and validation but we require everything handled in SimpleSAMLphp and OpenLDAP, Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

privacyIDEA can read your users and all needed attributes from OpenLDAP.
You can define an [attribute mapping](https://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/useridresolvers.html#ldap-resolver) to read any arbitrary attribute from OpenLDAP.

In privacyIDEA you can [define a policy](https://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/latest/policies/authentication.html#otppin), that requires the user to enter the LDAP password *plus* the OTP value.

Then in simpleSAMLphp you can define the *authsource* to be privacyIDEA.
This way you the user can authenticate with his LDAP password and the OTP at the IdP.
If you want to, you can use the paramter `otpextra` to even use a two step dialog, where the user first needs to enter his LDAP password and then his OTP value.

Use the [mapping in the SAML privacyIDEA module](https://github.com/privacyidea/simplesamlphp-module-privacyidea/blob/master/docs/privacyidea.txt#L62) or authproc filters to further map your attributes.

Comment: I have already included this solution in the description of my question..I want to know if OpenLDAP has some inbuilt feature for 2FA..You have answered my question twice

Comment: If you want to use inbuilt features (which of course come with different limitations) go for the suggestions of michael powers or  michael ströder !

Comment: Yeah looking into solution provided by @michael-powers, Yes also it's tedious job to work with OpenLDAP setup for an newbie

Comment: "privacyIDEA can read your users and all needed attributes from OpenLDAP" this can be done in privacyIDEA server right?

Comment: Yes, you can define the attribute mapping in the LDAP resolver in privacyIDEA.

Comment: Okay Thanks.. I'll be requiring you help if needed I have also joined privacyidea forum

Answer (score 1):

It looks like OpenLDAP does support [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) (most commonly referred to as Google Authenticator) with a slapd module.

The module for OpenLDAP can be [found here](https://github.com/openldap/openldap/tree/master/contrib/slapd-modules/passwd/totp). Article describing it can [be found here](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=openldap-totp-support). The documentation for the module seems a bit light but the module itself is small and fairly readable.

Comment: This is not actual 2FA solution User has to enter password(totp) only once no additional authentication is required.

Comment: The Github link says that one can combine a traditional password with a TOTP. I find this interesting link about how to set up TOTP for LDAP: https://blog.sys4.de/totp-time-based-one-time-password-authentication-en.html. Looking forward to find some more interesting articles describing this.

Answer (score 1):

In my [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com) I'm using my own solution [OATH-LDAP](https://oath-ldap.stroeder.com/) which adds the token data as LDAP entries. Currently the validator only supports counter-based HOTP (see [RFC 4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226)). It can be used e.g. with *yubikey* and there's also an enrollment script available for this.

Unfortunately there's currently no documentation available on how to use OATH-LDAP stand-alone in an arbitrary OpenLDAP installation.

Let me know if you want to dig into this.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also use the [privacyIDEA LDAP Proxy](https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea-ldap-proxy) to still use the `ldap:ldap` authsource of simpleSAMLphp but "enrich" this with an OTP value.